How do I directly access/include Bootstrap's _variable.scss from my React src folder?
As an example:

_variable.scss is located inside D:\projects\my-react-app\node_modules\bootstrap\scss

My custom SCSS is located inside D:\projects\my-react-app\src\assets\scss

I am importing Bootstrap's main CSS file into my App.tsx via this line:
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'



I'm hoping something similar can be used inside my custom SCSS.

bootstrap has both a scss version for sass compiling, and a regular css file for if you don't want to customize their styles. it looks like you are just using their regular css file, and not their scss version. if you want to do sass compiling and use an scss file, you will need to make sure your project is configured to do so.
if you are using a recent version of Vite or create-react-app for your react project, it should already be set up to compile sass, but you will still need to make sure you have a sass compiler installed. people usually use npm install sass.
after that, you should just be able to import scss files the same way you import regular css files. import ./App.scss
you can also do @use 'some.other.scss.file' inside your imported scss file to use that file's contents within your own scss file.
